Movie or mini series about orphan brothers in Liverpool
I'm looking for the name of a movie (I think it was a movie) I watched some years ago that I'm fairly certain had something to do with Liverpool, but I could be wrong. It involved I believe 3 or 4 brothers who were orphans. 
2 Scenes from the movie spring to mind whenever I think about it, the first is about one of the brothers losing their hearing after someone (who I think is a priest) hits him on the side of the head with a cane.
The second scene is when 2 of the brothers are at an orphanage that is currently digging up a piece of earth to be used as a swimming pool. One night it begins to rain and the hole starts filling up with water, the youngest brother for some reason wants to go out and swim during the rain storm. Long story short, while he's swimming the water level rises to a point where he can no longer get out and he drowns. The scene ends with the kid under water too tired to swim to the surface while an adult at the orphanage, who heard a commotion by the hole, is at the edge of the hole with a flash light searching for what made a noise, he isnt able to find anything though.
Thats all I remember from it, as I said, it could be either a movie or a mini-series.

You're looking for the harsh UK\Australian miniseries The Leaving of Liverpool from 1992. From Wiki:

The series follows two children—Lily (played by Christine Tremarco) and Bert (Kevin Jones)—who meet at the Star of the Sea Orphanage in Liverpool, England in the 1950s. They are transported to Australia, where they are placed in a labour camp, and later forced to work at a sheep station.

Both of the scenes you've described appear there. Well remembered.


Wow, yeah thats it! Thanks!
